# Having issues with Hibernate multiple @OneToOne relations to the same class objects

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have the following Hibernate mapping. I want to map two @OneToOne mapping to the same class objects but am having issues.

// Info class

```
public class Info {
@Id
@Column(name="info_id")
private String info_id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "info")
    private Diary dairy1;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "info")
    private Diary dairy2;

   // I use this method to set the dairy 
   public void setDairy(Dairy dairy) {
        if (getDairy1() == null) {
            setDairy1(dairy);
        } else if (getDairy2() == null) {
            setDairy2(dairy);
        }
    }

  // OTHER GETTERS EN SETTERS OMITTED
     
}
```

// Dairy class

```
public class Dairy {
            @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = "info_id")
            private Info info;
        }
```

The problem am facing now is when I save `Info` with `dairy1` set to a new `Dairy` object and later am retrieving `Info`, then both `dairy1` en `dairy2` are initialized with the same `dairy1` object. I expect `dairy2` to be **null** but it is initialized with the same `dairy1` object.

Comment: what is the concept here? each diary has an info which has two other diaries?

Answer (score 0):

With your current classes, one instance of `Info` can have relation to 2 instances of `Diary`. That's why definition `@OneToOne` is not correct here.

Without knowing what you problem are you trying to solve, based only on your code, following solution would be possible:

Define relation as `@OneToMany` in the `Info` class and as `@ManyToOne` in the `Diary` class. To distinguish instances of `Diary` in the same relation, you can add an attribute `order` to `Diary` and set values 1 or 2 correspondingly.